# How does merging work the second, third, etc. time you merge a file?

Tags: version-control, merge

I'm interested in knowing how revision-control systems do merging.

Suppose you have a file A. On one branch, file A is modified - call it file B. On another branch, file A is modified - call it file C:

```
  B
 /
A
 \
  C
```

When the second branch is merged into the first branch, I understand that a 3-way merge is performed between B, C, and their parent A. The result is file D on the first branch:

```
  B--D
 /
A
 \
  C
```

Now what I don't understand is what happens after another iteration. D is modified, becoming E, and C is modified, becoming F:

```
  B--D--E
 /
A
 \
  C--F
```

If we want to do another merge from the second branch to the first, what are the 3 files involved in the 3-way merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a concrete example using Git (other version control systems will be different). When you merge B and C together, you get history that looks something like this:

```
  B---D
 /   /
A   /
 \ /
  C
```

At this point, D has two parents, B and C. After you do more work and introduce E and F and do a merge, you will get something like:

```
  B---D--E--G
 /   /     /
A   /     /
 \ /     /
  C-----F
```

In the merge, the closest common parent between E and F is C.

The [git merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) documentation has more examples and descriptions of how this works. Also, the [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/) article has more descriptions, examples, and even better pictures (start with the "History" section for merge discussion.)

Answer (score -1):

I guess the 3 files involved are E, F, and A. See Fig 3-16 in http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html